# Redhat wal-e installation

Tags: redhat, database-backup

I am trying to get https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e installed on a Redhat system. I have been using the pip method to do the installations. I believe I installed all required dependencies and it's still throwing the distribution not found error. See the output below.

`wal-e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wal-e", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in 
    working_set.require(requires)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-keystoneclient>=0.4.2`

I am not familiar with Python what so ever but I would have assumed installing a package would be easy enough. Any help with this would be great.

When I do a pip list I see python-keystoneclient (0.10.1) in the output. To me that means it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue. The solution was I also had to install the setuptools package in Python.

`sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`

After I did this everything loaded up properly and worked. Not sure why the documentation wouldn't have this step in it.